# iterate through column to match with dict values

Tags: python, string, dictionary, isin

I have a dict similar to this:

```
dict = {'color':['red', 'blue', 'green'], 'fruits':['apple', 'banana', 'grape'], 'animal':['cat', 'dog']}
```

and df with two columns; text column with multiple strings:

```
index   |   text
-------------------------------
a       | house, chair, green
-------------------------------
b       | yellow, banana, wall
--------------------------------
c       | dog, brown, grass
--------------------------------
```

I would like to add extra column to df with key pair from dict if any string from text column is matching with dict.values, so for a - color / b - fruits / c - animal.

I was trying with `isin` for lists but thought maybe with dict would be more efficient.? Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html).

```
def get_type(input_strs):
    for key, val in type_dict:
        for input_str in input_strs:
            if input_str in val:
                return key

df["str_type"] = df["text"].apply(get_type)
```

However, keep in mind that `apply()` is poorly optimized- it's roughly equivalent to using a for loop to apply the function.

If performance is a concern you might consider inverting your dictionary like `{"red":"color", "blue":"color" ...}` and writing a simpler function to apply like

```
def get_type(input_strs):
    for input_str in input_strs:
        if input_str in type_dict:
            return type_dict[input_str]
```

You could also consider using one of the optimized functions for series of strs in pandas like [`extract()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) assuming that `df["text"]` is a series of strs, not lists of strs. There are no optimized pandas functions for series of lists, and it's generally a bad idea to keep lists in DataFrames if performance is a priority.